# Ng-model & Ng-model-options issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to use both `ng-model` and `ng-model-options`on an input. `Ng-model` is used to ensure a user can only input numbers into the input with the following directive:

```
angular.module('officeNetApp').directive('onlyNumbers', function() {
    return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      console.log('TEST');
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           if (inputValue === undefined) {
            return '';
           }
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
            if (transformedInput!==inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }     
           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
  });
```

`ng-model-options` is being used to update the input on blur. I'm doing this so that validation is triggered on blur like so:

```
<input type="text" id="forwardedFrom" name="forwardedFrom" ng-model="numbers" class="vfnz-input--text" placeholder="Forwarded from" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" only-numbers="only-numbers" required />
```

For some reason when I remove `ng-model-options` the directive functionality works enabling a user to only input numbers. I can't have them both as I need both to enable the required functionality.

Unsure why I can't use both / Unsure of another approach to achieve what I'm after.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oyLvoe5p/3/)

Comment: If I put `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` in the <input>, I now can type letters in the text box, and they are not removed until I click off of it. Without that, I can't type letters at all. Is this not what you are seeing? Or not the intended behavior?

Comment: Sorry - updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oyLvoe5p/3/

Comment: In your fiddle, you're missing the dependency list in the module definition - should be angular.module('myApp', []). But after fixing that I see the same behavior as Dana...what's the intended behavior?